Update issues with Gradle in Android Studio
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip'.
Reason: java.net.UnknownHostException: github.com
Please ensure gradle distribution url is correct.
If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings.
I followed several videos on You Tube but none of them hit the nail on the head
I have the latest version of Medusa installed and in theory I have the latest version of Gradle installed but it still shows me that message

Can you please update your question and copy&paste the content of your gradle-wrapper.properties? That file should be in some subdirectory of your project, possibly gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Visit https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip in a Web browser. Can you download the file? If the answer is no, talk to your ISP or networking team, as that is a valid URL for downloading Gradle 8.6.
